# TableToGeodatabase result to Attribute Index

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, csv, feature-class

I am converting a csv to a Geodatabase, then I want to add an index using the AddIndex_management().  How do I get the output of the TableToGeodatabase() method to be a layer I can use as the input for the AddIndex_management() method.  I tried using result.getOutput(0), but that did not seem to work.

```
def convert_csv(csv_file, ws):
    '''converts csv to geodb'''
    parcel_info_fc = arcpy.TableToGeodatabase_conversion(csv_file, ws)
    return parcel_info_fc
    '''This doesn't return anything, it simple transfers something,  I need to figure out
    how to create an output.'''


def add_attri_index(feature_class, index_field, ws):
    '''adds attribute index to parcel info table
    and the parcel shape file table'''
    arcpy.env.workspace = ws
    print("Working on index for ", feature_class)
    arcpy.env.workspace = ws
    arcpy.AddIndex_management(feature_class, index_field, 'PI2', 'NON_UNIQUE', 'NON_ASCENDING')

    time.sleep(10)



def main(csv_file, parcel_layer, ParcelID_field, ws):

    parcel_info = convert_csv(csv_file, ws).getOutput

    add_attri_index(parcel_layer, ParcelID_field, ws)
    add_attri_index(parcel_info, 'APN', ws)
```

I get a RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool. I am guessing this is because the result type from my convert_csv function is a `<bound method Result.getOutput of <Result 'D:\\...\\MyGeoDB.gdb'>>`

Comment: Thank you, I will give the getOutput(0) another go.  I could not get it to work using both parcel_into_fc.arcpy.getOutput(0) and parcel_info_fc.getOutput(0).  Both error-ed  with 'Result' object as no attribute 'arcpy' or 'getOutput'.   Was able to get around this by renaming my path so that I could just call the path in add_attri_index(x, y, z), but I can see how this may not be as robust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All geoprocessing tools return Result objects which you then query for the output, in your case a table. Your code implies that it is directly returning a table which is incorrect it is a result object. You would return full path to table with `getOutput(0)`. Read the help file about [result objects](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/result.htm).